# pybind11 interpreter use bundled python executable

Tags: python, c++, qmake, pybind11

I am using the pybind11 interpreter within a c++ application. I don't build with CMake but qmake due to legacy reasons, unfortunately. Hence, I am struggling to understand how to properly setup the pybind11 interpreter.
The c++ application will ship with a bundled python 3.7 (so on Mac the app bundle will ship with the python.framework)

The interpreter should use the bundled python (`MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python`) but when printing `sys.exec_prefix` it always falls back to whatever it finds installed, so in my case: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python`

My .pro setup looks like this:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/$$PWD/../3rdParty/python
LIBS += -framework Python

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../3rdParty/python/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../3rdParty/python/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
```

How can I tell pybind11 / my executable what python executable and environment to use? The target user should not be forced to install python to run my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to set `PYTHONHOME` to `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7`

and `PYTHONPATH` to  `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7`

In Qt I do that by calling `qputenv` before `py::scoped_interpreter guard{};`

Comment: instead of using qputenv it seems to be a good idea to call 'Py_SetPythonHome' and 'Py_SetPath' instead